# Declare In-Memory Table Using Defined Fields

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I want to create an in-memory table that can behave like:

```
let table1Count = Table1
| count;
let table2Count = Table2
| count;
let stats = datatable (name: string, counts: real)
[
    "Table 1 Entries: ", table1Count ,
    "Table 2 Entries: ", table2Count 
];
```

If I try to do this in Kusto, it won't accept table1Count or table2Count as valid values.  So is there another way to declare a table using fields that are set at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
let table1Count = T
| count;
let table2Count = T1
| count;
let stats1 = print name="Table 1 Entries", counts = toscalar(table1Count);
let stats2 = print name="Table 2 Entries", counts = toscalar(table2Count);
union stats1, stats2
```

[image: Screenshots of he result]